# count the number of "yes" in a spark dataframe column

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to count the number of "yes" in a column of the Spark Data Frame.

Input DF:

```
col_1

yes
no
yes
no
```

Op:

```
2
```

Code:

```
df.groupBy("col_1").agg(count("col_1")).collect()
```

Then iterate through the Array to fetch the value. Is there an efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `select` with `sum` and `when` inbuilt function

## pyspark

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
df.select(f.sum(f.when(f.col('col_1') == 'yes', 1)).alias('count')).show(truncate=False)
```

## scala

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.select(sum(when(col("col_1") === "yes", 1)).as("count")).show(false)
```

which should give you

```
+-----+
|count|
+-----+
|2    |
+-----+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Answer (score 2):

Why not simple filter:

```
df.filter('col_1 === "yes").count
```

Or

```
df.groupBy('col_1).agg(sum(when($"col_1" === "yes", 1).otherwise(0)).as("yes_cnt")).show
```

Comment: are there any performance difference between these three approaches (select, filter, groupBy)?